# xcode navigation button url

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

I am trying to add a "Home" button to my app, where if you click on a button in the toolbar, if will take you to a specific url "google.com".

So I can put a button in the nav bar, and make it say home.

and I can put this in the viewcontroller.m:

```
-(void)openGoogleURL
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com"]];
}
```

Is what I put in viewcontroller correct?  How do I hook up my button?

Comment: The pattern is called target-action. Google for it.

Comment: None of the other things worked for me.  But I used what you said to help guide me towards a tutorial that DID work.  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JhDQ9Vj4RdY&list=PLC7CF6322ED52EDC9&index=2

Answer (score 1):

`UINavigationController` uses a `UINavigationItem` object of each `UIViewController` to display the items in navigation bar. So you can add the button you want in the bar by doing something like this on your View Controller:

```
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(openGoogleURL)]];
```

That way the button target-action will be linked with the function you've defined in your UIViewController.

Note that for every view controller you want to add this button, you'll need this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can wire the button click event to your code either programmatically or by using Interface Builder. Here's some documentation from the Apple's website: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/TargetAction.html